# Daily Aggregation and R

Tags: r

I'm trying to get a daily average temperature reading in R. Unfortunately my code

```
df_energyData$temperature <- as.numeric(df_energyData$temperature)
aggregate(df_energyData[,1:2], by = list(df_energyData$time), FUN = mean)
```

has given me a per 15 minute average temperature reading.

```
Group.1                time temperature
1    2018-08-15 00:15:00 2018-08-15 00:15:00          69
2    2018-08-15 00:30:00 2018-08-15 00:30:00          68
3    2018-08-15 00:45:00 2018-08-15 00:45:00          69
...
```

My data in general looks like

```
time                 temperature
2018-08-15 00:15:00  69
2018-08-15 00:30:00  68
2018-08-15 00:45:00  69
...
```

Sorry for how everything's formatted. I'm pretty new to stack and coding in general so I'm not sure how to make these lists look pretty.

Comment: It good if you put copy paste a sample from dput(head(YOUR_DATA))

Comment: structure(list(time = structure(c(1534328100, 1534355100, 1534382100, 
1534410900, 1534437900, 1534464900), class = c("POSIXct", "POSIXt"
), tzone = ""), temperature = c(69, 82, 74, 69, 77, 70), electricity = c("22286641.422", 
"22310196.941", "22331332.781", "22346146.061", "22368667.180", 
"22390954.060")), .Names = c("time", "temperature", "electricity"
), row.names = c(NA, 6L), class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a solution that works

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)

# Convert to date

data$time <- ymd_hms(data$time)

# Use date function to only use the datestamp

data %>% group_by(date(time)) %>% summarise(mean_temp = mean(temperature))
```

If you are you familiar with the %>% and want to use the aggregate function in your original code, the following will give you the same result:

```
aggregate(data[, 2], by = list(date(data$time)), FUN = mean)
```